# Tkinter paste image in textbox from clipboard

Tags: python, image, tkinter, clipboard

I am trying to paste get an image from clipboard and paste it into the textbox/label in tkinter. My code is below.

```
# page4 buttons and functions

f7 = Frame(page4)
f7.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')

f8 = Frame(page4)
f8.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NESW')

tb8 = Label(f7, width=82)
tb8.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')

tb9 = Text(f7, width=30)
tb9.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NESW')


 def imgps():
   try:
    image = root.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image))
    tb8.config(page4, image=img)
    tb8.clipboard_clear()
  except:
    messagebox.showinfo(message="Clipboard is Empty.")

 pbtn11 = Button(f8, text="IMAGE", activebackground="lavender",
            activeforeground="RoyalBlue", bd="5", bg="aquamarine2",
            command=imgps, fg="purple", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
 pbtn11.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')
```

Nothing appears on the area intended and neither any error is shown up. But, whence I close the application. the Messagebox turns up. Seems like weird coding. Can somebody  help.

Comment: You cannot paste an image into a text-box. However you can to a label. The correct wat to do this to a label is not to try to insert it but rather assign the image to the image attribute of the label. `label_name.config(image = image_object)`. You will also need to save a reference to the image.

Comment: okay, but should this be inside the function `imgps` or outside. I am using a variable img but it cannot be used outside function. I have tried using inside the function nothing appears same status.

Comment: It can be in or out. That only matter depending on what you are trying to accomplish. As long as the label already exist you can use the `config()` method. You may also create the image object and assign it to the label during the time you defined the label. `tb8 = Label(f7, width=82, image=image_object)`.

Comment: when I try to use outside function as `tb8 = Label(f7, width=82, image=img)`. It gives error as unresolved reference.

Comment: That will happen. You need to also either define the image in the global namespace before the label creation. I was simply saying it can be done in both the function or in the global.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of adding an image to the label.

Keep in mind you will need to make sure that a reference to the image is saved or else you will not see an image in your app.

Update:

I believe this updated answer should work for you. The code will try to grab the image from clipboard using the `ImageGrab` method in `PIL` if there is one and then it saves the image to a temp folder. We then load that image to the label and then delete the image from the temp folder.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, ImageGrab

root = tk.Tk()
tb8 = tk.Label(root, width=82)
tb8.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

def imgps():
    try:
        temp_path = "./TempImage/some_image.gif" # Whatever temp path you want here
        im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard() # Get image from clipboard
        im.save(temp_path) # save image to temp folder
        load_for_label = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=temp_path) # load image from temp folder
        tb8.config(image=load_for_label) # set image to label
        tb8.image = load_for_label # save reference to image in memory
        tb8.clipboard_clear() # clear clipboard
        os.remove(temp_path) # delete temp file
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Clipboard is Empty.")

pbtn11 = tk.Button(root, text="IMAGE", command=imgps)
pbtn11.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

I did try several ways to load the image directly from the clipboard but I kept running into errors. So my above solutions might not be 100% the fastest way to implement this but should work well enough.

Comment: The major issue I am facing is that the path issue. I am trying to get the image from clipboard. If you see my function I am trying to get the clipboard image to be pasted into label. And, the see the code again please. I have modified accordingly.

Comment: Interestingly, everytime I try to paste the image from function. The messagebox appears after almost 4sec telling me the Clipboard is empty. this  is of course I have put an option. Something is failing.

Comment: Let me see what I can come up with. I have not had to use the clipboard on images before.

Comment: Thanks! I shall try tomorrow, feeling sleepy for now, and shall give you a follow up.

Comment: Hi! good morning I have tried the code but run into issue with `ImageGrab`. This actually works on Windows and MacOS only, mine is Ubuntu. Can we use pyscreenshot instead. Not finding any success.

Comment: Sometimes there are these kind of limitations between OS's. I am off for the night but I will look into it when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! It's great learning here. I am tying to explore pyscreenshot it also has ImageGrab

Comment: @AmbrishDhaka pyscreenshot does have a module named ImageGrab but it does not perform all the same functions as PIL's ImageGrab. For example there is not clipboard method to go with the ImageGrab of pyscreenshot. The only python library I can find that looks like it can work for linux is GTK.

Comment: Thanks, I have given up the idea of clipboard altogether, and now I am using the stored images for retrieval. Acturally, I need all this stuff for OCR function. Almost succeeded in writing one in python.

Comment: There are a few examples out there that appear to work for linux however at work I do not have a linux distro so I cannot test them. Good luck on your other idea though hope it works out.